# How to Ensure Memory Visibility in Java when passing data across threads

Tags: java, multithreading, memory-management, shared-memory, java-memory-model

I have a producer consumer like pattern where some threads are creating data and periodically passing putting chunks of that data to be consumed by some other threads.

Keeping the Java Memory Model in mind, how do i ensure that the data passed to the consumer thread has full 'visibility'?

I know there are data structures in java.util.concurrent like ConcurrentLinkedQueue that are built specifically for this, but I want to do this as low level as possible without utilizing those and have full transparency on what is going on under the covers to ensure the memory visibility part.

Comment: *"full transparency on what is going on under the covers to ensure the memory visibility part."* - do you not trust `ConcurrentLinkedQueue`?

Comment: as a side note, ConcurrentLinkedQueue is not great for producer/consumer as it has no blocking facilities.  generally, the BlockingQueue implementations are ideal for producer/consumer.

Answer (score 1):

If you want "low level" then look into `volatile` and `synchronized`.

Answer (score 1):

To transfer data, you need a field somewhere available to all threads.  In your case it really needs to be some sort of collection to handle multiple entries.  If you made the field `final`, referencing, say, a ConcurrentLinkedQueue, you'd pretty much be done.  The field could be made public and everyone could see it, or you could make it available with a getter.

If you use an unsynchronized queue, you have more work to do, because you have to manually synchronize all access to it, which means you have to track down all usages; not easy when there's a getter method.  Not only do you need to protect the queue from simultaneous access, you must make sure interdependent calls end up in the same synchronized block.  For instance:

```
    if (!queue.isEmpty())  obj = queue.remove();
```

If the whole thing is not synchronized, `queue` is perfectly capable of telling you it is not empty, then throwing a NoSuchElementException when you try to get the next element.  (ConcurrentLinkedQueue's interface is specifically designed to let you do operations like this with one method call.  Take a good look at it even if you don't want to use it.)

The simple solution is to wrap the queue in another object whose methods are carefully chosen *and* all synchronized.  The wrapped class, even if it's LinkedList or ArrayList, will now act (if you do it right) like CLQ, and it can be freely released to the rest of the program.

**So you would have** what is really a global field with an immutable (`final`) reference to a wrapper class, which contains a LinkedList (for example) and has synchronized methods that use the LinkedList to store and access data.  The wrapper class, like CLQ, would be thread-safe.

Some variants on this might be desirable.  It might make sense to combine the wrapper with some other high-level class in your program.  It might also make sense to create and make available instances of nested classes:  perhaps one that only adds to the queue and one that only removes from it.  (You couldn't do this with CLQ.)

A final note:  having synchronized everything, the next step is to figure out how to unsynchronize (to keep threads from waiting too much) without breaking thread safety.  Work really hard on *this*, and you'll end up rewriting ConcurrentLinkedQueue.